# Convergence in metric space and show cauchy sequence in metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I consider a metric space ($C^1(\mathbb{R}), \mathbb{R}$), $\Vert \cdot \Vert_u$) where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_u$ is the uniform norm, and I want to show that for $f_n \in C^1$, that is the continous differentiable function $f_n: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ the sequence $(f_n)$ is convergent in the metric space.

Say that I found the limit of the function sequence to be f. Do I then need to show that f belongs to the metric space AND $\Vert f - f_n \Vert_u \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ in order to show that the sequence converges in the metric space?

And assume (for simplicity) that $f_n(x) = (x - 1/n)^2$. Is the following argument correct, if I want to conclude that $f_n$ is a cauchy sequence in the metric space:
Since $|f_n - f_m| =  |(x-1/n)^2-(x-1/m)^2| \rightarrow 0$ for $n,m \rightarrow \infty$ then it holds that:
$\Vert f_n - f_m \Vert_u = sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f_n - f_m| \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and the sequence is cauchy in the metric space.

Answer (score 1):

"Say that I found the limit of the function sequence to be f. Do I then need to show that f belongs to the metric space AND $∥f−fn∥u→0$ for $n→∞$
 in order to show that the sequence converges in the metric space?

Yes, that is pretty much the **definition** of "convergence" here!

"And assume (for simplicity) that $f_n(x)=(x−1/n)^2$. Is the following argument correct, if I want to conclude that fn is a cauchy sequence in the metric space: Since $|fn−fm|=|(x−1/n)^2−(x−1/m)^2|→0$ for $n,m→∞$
 then it holds that: $∥fn−fm∥=supx∈R|fn−fm|→0$ for $n,m→∞$
 and the sequence is cauchy in the metric space."

Yes.  How have you shown that first "since"?

Comment: Thanks! About the "Since": Yes that is the thing. From the sole look of the function $f_n(x) = (x-1/n)^2$ I find it obvious that since $1/n  \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $ |f_n - f_m| = |(x-1/n)^2-(x-1/m)^2| \rightarrow |x^2 - x^2| = 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ but is that correct reasoning?